# How to send message to HttpResponseRedirect in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have added a middleware to a session-out user with my logic. I am trying to redirect to login page with a message. I am using HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_login')) for redirecting to my custom login page.
So, how to pass values to a page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use django's messages framework. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/

In your views do:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success(request, 'This is my message.')
```

And in your base template keep this piece of code.

```
{% if messages %}<ul class="messages">
{% for message in messages %}
<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
{% endfor %}</ul>{% endif %}
```

Or if don't want to use messages you can pass in the url.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_login') + '?autologout=true')
```

And in your template

```
{% if request.GET.autologout %}
<p>This is my message.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @Rijo did it help ?

Comment: I don't want to use 'messages'.

Comment: Then what about passing a get parameter in the url and display the message only if the parameter in the url ?